# compress multiple files into a bz2 file in python

Tags: python, bz2

I need to compress multiple files into one bz2 file in python. 
I'm trying to find a way but I can't can find an answer. 
Is it possible?

Comment: `bz2` has no concept of a "file". All it knows is "data". If you want to merge multiple files into a single bz2-compressed chunk of data, you have to find a way to split that data into individual files upon decompressing. This is not something that bz2 supports natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what tarballs are for. The `tar` format packs the files together, then you compress the result. Python makes it easy to do both at once with [the `tarfile` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html), where passing a "mode" of `'w:bz2'` opens a new tar file for write with seamless `bz2` compression. Super-simple example:

```
import tarfile

with tarfile.open('mytar.tar.bz2', 'w:bz2') as tar:
    for file in mylistoffiles:
        tar.add(file)
```

If you don't need much control over the operation, [`shutil.make_archive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive) might be a possible alternative, which would simplify the code for compressing a whole directory tree to:

```
shutil.make_archive('mytar', 'bztar', directory_to_compress)
```

Comment: If you try to bunzip2 the file created using the tarfile w:bz2 method, you get 1 file, not a set of files.

Comment: @RyanR.Rosario: Yes, that's how tarballs work; `tar` packs everything into one file, and a separate compressor compresses the result. If you want to decompress and extract, you either `bunzip2` to decompress, then use `tar` to extract, or on most `tar` variants, you can just do `tar xJf myfile.tar.bz2` and it will both decompress and extract as a single step.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at python's bz2 library. Make sure to google and read the docs first!

https://docs.python.org/2/library/bz2.html#bz2.BZ2Compressor

Comment: I did it but it only receives "data" as input, not a folder or a bunch of files

Comment: In fact I'm looking maybe it's not possible... https://superuser.com/questions/1287672/how-to-bzip2-multiple-files-into-one-single-archive-file here it says that bzip2 command only receives one file

Answer (score 0):

you have import package for:

```
import tarfile,bz2
```

and multilfile compress in bz format

```
tar = tarfile.open("save the directory.tar.bz", "w:bz2")
for f in ["gti.png","gti.txt","file.taz"]:
    tar.add(os.path.basename(f))
tar.close()
```

let use for in zip format was open in a directory open file

an use

```
os.path.basename(src_file)
```

open a only for file

Answer (score 0):

Python's standard lib [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) handles multiple files and has supported bz2 compression since 2001.

```
import zipfile
sourcefiles = ['a.txt', 'b.txt']
with zipfile.ZipFile('out.zip', 'w') as outputfile:
   for sourcefile in sourcefiles:
      outputfile.write(sourcefile, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_BZIP2)
```